# how to create a search bar input to search every columns of the table using php

Tags: php, mysqli

I am creating a search bar which will search the query from every column of my database table and will prompt the output I am doing this with php and mysqli but now I dont have any idea to how do I show my output. can anybody help me 
here is my code

```
if(!$db) {
    require("includes/db.php")
    echo 'ERROR: Could not connect to the database.';
} else {
    if(isset($_POST['queryString'])) {
        $queryString = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['queryString']);
        if(strlen($queryString) >0) {
            $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM mdb  WHERE name LIKE '%" . $queryString . "%' OR grno LIKE '%". $queryString ."%'
                                    OR `address` LIKE '%". $queryString ."%', `city` LIKE '%". $queryString ."%' OR pin LIKE '%". $queryString ."%'
                                    OR mobile LIKE '%". $queryString ."%' OR `email` LIKE'%". $queryString ."%'  ORDER BY vouchno LIMIT 8");


            if($query) {
                $catid = 0;
                while ($result = $query ->fetch_object()) {
                    //no idea how do I show the result here
                }
```

Comment: You should have a look on basic database design. What you are trying to do is nasty nasty, it's better just to paste everything in a text file and preg_match on it instead Lol

Comment: so can u help me in showing of wht is to be done

Comment: to start... why do you need to search in ALL columns? what type of information do they contain? that's not very natural

Comment: well every column does contain's the value i need and i want that if i type anything which is present in that field then all the records associated with that data should be output for eg. if i enter 123 and 123 is present in the mobile den the name, address, city, pin should be output along with the mobile number

Comment: but then that could return you a lot of rows, cos maybe 123 is in a lot of other mobile phone numbers, address numbers, descriptions, etc. Shouldn't it be better to have a few select boxes to filter the sarch by city or whatever ?

Comment: yea that ws jus an example like if a person wants to get the record of someone and he knows only his mobile  number then he can search it by putting his mobile number into search field or he can input his name to get his mobile  number or whtever

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just to answer your question heres the code

```
if(!$db) {
require("includes/db.php")
echo 'ERROR: Could not connect to the database.';
} else {
if(isset($_POST['queryString'])) {
    $queryString = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['queryString']);
    if(strlen($queryString) >0) {
        $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM mdb  WHERE name LIKE '%" . $queryString . "%' OR grno LIKE '%". $queryString ."%'
                                OR `address` LIKE '%". $queryString ."%', `city` LIKE '%". $queryString ."%' OR pin LIKE '%". $queryString ."%'
                                OR mobile LIKE '%". $queryString ."%' OR `email` LIKE'%". $queryString ."%'  ORDER BY vouchno LIMIT 8");


        if($query) {
            $catid = 0;
            $results = array();
            while ($result = $query ->fetch_object()) {
                //no idea how do I show the result here
                $results[] = $result;
            }

            /* use the $results to show the result using foreach or forloop*/
```

But please consider the comments above.

Comment: thnks alot but is it necessary to use for loop?